# Order screens Alphabetically in react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to order my screens automatically in alphabetical order. So I can just add a screen to the bottom and not worry about its position in the list. And I have a TON of screens.

Here is my code (I deleted some screens because there were too many, and did not post my imports) :

```
export const Root = DrawerNavigator({

  Home: { screen: Home },
  About: { screen: About },
  Administration: { screen: Administration },
  CSF: { screen: CSF },
  Calendar: { screen: Calendar },
  Directory: { screen: Directory },
  HNN: { screen: HNN },
  NHS: {screen: NHS},
  IB: { screen: IB },
  ID: { screen: ID },
  Site: { screen: Site },
  WebStore: { screen: WebStore },


}, {
  // drawer config
  //drawerWidth: 239, //drawer width //auto size for device

  contentComponent: props => <ScrollView><DrawerItems {...props} /></ScrollView>, //scrolling drawer
  //backBehavior: 'none', //currently makes back button do nothing
  drawerPosition: 'right',
  drawerBackgroundColor: 'whitesmoke',
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen', //stuff that prevents errors
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',  //stuff that prevents errors
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle', //stuff that prevents errors
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#63461E', //brown active text
    inactiveTintColor: '#7F6D45', //light brown inactive text
    style: {
      marginVertical: 9,

    }
  }
  //end drawer config
});
```

Is this even possible?
How can I achieve this?

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to do with javascript about this, it's just about how your code editor do this automatically for you.

For Visual Studio Code, you can use plugin [Sort JSON Object](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richie5um2.vscode-sort-json), that may works for you.

> Alphabetically sorts the keys in selected JSON objects.